# Ignore DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE for the Django Admin Site?

Tags: xhtml, django-admin

What would be the best way to go about forcing all `HttpResponse` objects returned by views in the Django admin site app to use "text/html" as their content type, regardless of the value of the `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` setting? My project has this set to "application/xhtml+xml," and although content produced by the admin app claims to be valid XHTML (look at its doctype declaration), it is not. [Ticket #5704](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5704) is a major problem, and I discovered some issues with inline forms (namely a liberal use of `&nbsp;`, which is not a named entity in XHTML). A comment in [Ticket #11684](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11684) indicates that it may be a while before the admin site will fully support XHTML, so I need to figure out how to use "text/html" for the admin site, while leaving the default as "application/xhtml+xml."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it or not, but I finally achieved my goal by subclassing `AdminSite` and overriding the `admin_view` method:

```
class HTMLAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    '''Django AdminSite that forces response content-types to be text/html

    This class overrides the default Django AdminSite `admin_view` method. It
    decorates the view function passed and sets the "Content-Type" header of
    the response to 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
    '''

    def _force_html(self, view):
        def force_html(*arguments, **keywords):
            response = view(*arguments, **keywords)
            response['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
            return response
        return force_html

    def admin_view(self, view, *arguments, **keywords):
        return super(HTMLAdminSite, self).admin_view(self._force_html(view),
                                                     *arguments, **keywords)
```

Then, in my root URLconf, before calling `admin.autodiscover()`, I set `admin.site` to an instance of this `HTMLAdminSite` class. It seems to work okay, but if there's a better way, I'd be glad to hear it.